# re.split to split expression and keep delimeters/with brackets involved

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm working with multiple expressions that look like this
`C=>E` or `A+B+C=>D` or `A+B<=>C` and `(F|G)+H=>E`. I am trying to use `re.split()` to split on `=>` or `<=>`. Furthermore I want to also split along the 3 operators `+ | ^` while not touching what's inside brackets.

First attempt, I've tried this

```py
re.split(r"<=>|=>", "A+B+C=>D")
```

but the problem with this is it splits a line like `A+B+C=>D` to

```py
["A+B", "D"]
```

whereas I'm trying to achieve

```py
["A+B", "=>", "D"]
```

and also with the problem regarding operators when I try to split `(A+B)|C=>D` like this

```py
re.split(r"\+|=>|<=>|\^|\|", "(A+B)|C=>D")
```

I get

```py
["(A", "B)", "C", "D"]
```

whereas I'm trying to achieve

```py
["(A + B)", "|", "C", "=>", "D"]
```

I'm not very good with regex so I need help with possibly a regular expression robust enough to do this in one go. If it's not possible with regex, at least a better way of doing it.

Comment: The first example is wrong, `re.split(r"<=>|=>", "A+B+C=>D")` returns `['A+B+C', 'D']`, not `["A+B", "D"]`

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'\([^()]*\)|<?=>|[-+/*|^]|\w+', s)`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rgHH26/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are a life saver. I'm gonna try and interpret what you are doing in this regex but thank you.

Comment: @SASSY_ROG See [the answer with explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55792822/3832970) and hints on how to enhance the pattern below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'\([^()]*\)|<?=>|[-+/*|^]|\w+', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rgHH26/1) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5C(%5B%5E()%5D*%5C)%7C%3C%3F%3D%3E%7C%5B-%2B%2F*%7C%5E%5D%7C%5Cw%2B):

[image]

**Details**

- `\([^()]*\)` - a parenthesized substring
- `|` - or
- `<?=>` - a `<=>` or `=>`
- `|` - or
- `[-+/*|^]` - one of the chars defined in the character class (to match any non-word and non-whitespace char, you may replace it with `[\w\s]`)
- `|` - or
- `\w+` - word chars, 1 or more (you may precise it as you need: `[A-Z]+` will match 1 or more uppercase letters, `[a-zA-Z]+` will match 1+ letters)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a capture group:

```
import re

print(re.split(r"'(\^|=>)", "A+B+C=>D"))
# ['A+B+C', '=>', 'D']
```

Comment: Thanks that solves my first problem, my second problem now is not touching what's inside brackets while splitting with operators e.g `(A+B)^C=>E` to `["(A+B)", "^", "C", "=>", "E"]`

Comment: @SASSY_ROG `re.split(r'(\^|=>)', '(A+B)^C=>E')` but I'm not sure why you insist on using `re.split`

Comment: Great, one of the comments above showed me to use `re.findall()` which works